# Trouble when Dissolving Geopandas Polygons

Tags: python, dissolve, geopandas

I have dissolved polygons with geopandas. However, the head of attribute table became values of this table.

How can I fix this trouble?

See:

[image: Raw data]

[image: After dissolve]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple dissolve by GeoDataFrame field ([Aggregation with dissolve](http://geopandas.org/aggregation_with_dissolve.html?))

```
import geopandas as gpd
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
continents = world.dissolve('continent')
continents.head(3)
```

[image]

But if we use `as_index=False` from [Pandas DataFrame.groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
continents2 = world.dissolve('continent', as_index=False)
continents2.head(3)
```

[image]

Examine the GeoPandas [test_dissolve.py](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/3d397985030d71acdfcd50b0de0ff953d72cd9c2/geopandas/tests/test_dissolve.py) script

#### New

It is a problem of indexing in DataFrame.groupby

```
import geopandas as gpd
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
continents = world.dissolve('continent')
type(continents)
<class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
continents.index
Index([u'Africa', u'Antarctica', u'Asia', u'Europe', u'North America',
   u'Oceania', u'Seven seas (open ocean)', u'South America'],
  dtype='object', name=u'continent')
```

continents is a GeoDataFrame with a hierarchical index

With

```
 continents2 = world.dissolve('continent', as_index=False)
```

You eliminate the  hierarchical index and  you have the columns again

Comment: Very good! Thank you! What does it means "as_index"? Do you know?

Comment: Look above in New

Comment: as_index=False is much better than resetting the index, thank you